# Using CRTP with partial class specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to mix-in an `operator []` with a class.  My problem is I've partially specialized the class, and the compiler doesn't like me not specifying the template parameters to the derived class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct mixin {
    template <typename U>
    void operator[](U u) {
        cout << u;
    }
};


template <typename T, typename = void>
struct derived : mixin<derived> {};


template <typename T>
struct derived<T, 
    typename enable_if<
        is_same<T, int>{}
    >::type> : mixin<derived> {};


int main() {
    derived<int> d;
    d[3.14];
}
```

With clang this gives:

```
test.cc:16:24: error: use of class template 'derived' requires template arguments
struct derived : mixin<derived> {};
                       ^~~~~~~
test.cc:16:8: note: template is declared here
struct derived : mixin<derived> {};
       ^
test.cc:23:22: error: use of class template 'derived' requires template arguments
    >::type> : mixin<derived> {};
                     ^~~~~~~
test.cc:16:8: note: template is declared here
struct derived : mixin<derived> {};
       ^
```

gcc is even less helpful:

```
test.cc:16:31: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> struct mixin’
 struct derived : mixin<derived> {};
                               ^
test.cc:16:31: note:   expected a type, got ‘derived’
test.cc:23:29: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> struct mixin’
     >::type> : mixin<derived> {};
                             ^
test.cc:23:29: note:   expected a type, got ‘derived’
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
```

Is my only option to re-specify the template parameters inside of the mixin clause?

Comment: Why does your mixin need to be templated on T if all it has is a method templated on U?

Comment: I didn't put it in here but I need to downcast back to the base class, which is giving me it's own headaches...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct mixin {
    template <typename U>
    void operator[](U u) {
        cout << u;
    }
};


template <typename T, typename = void>
struct derived : mixin<derived<T>> {};


template <typename T>
struct derived<T,
    typename enable_if<
        is_same<T, int>::value
    >::type> : mixin<derived<T>> {};


int main() {
    derived<int> d;
    d[3.14];
}
```

It does [work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac3f8d53a830bd80)...

What I changed:

1. Using `is_same<foo,bar>::value`, not `is_same<foo,bar>{}` **edit:** Hmm, it seems you don't need to change that after all. Neat!
2. Not trying to get the compiler to deduce the template parameter for derived when using `mixin<derived>`. You were being *way* too optimistic there...

Comment: Passing the type explicitly like that does work (thankfully don't have to include the entire enable_if clause), it makes me sad I can't use the injected name though.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister: I don't think template parameter deduction is even attempted here, although IANALL.

Comment: Shame.  Btw the is_same<...>{} trick works because it instantiates is_same<> which is either true_type or false_type so {} gives you true or false =D

Comment: My thought was not to infer deduce, but to use the injected name.  In the body of the class, either_ in a type-context really means either_<A,B>

Comment: @SeanMcAllister: "In the both of a class" may be the key phrase in your comment.